# Angular - Can't bind property since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Tags: angular, data-binding, components

I have a list of objects and by clicking one of them I need to open a modal and show some properties of that object.

My code looks like this:

Object Component:

```
export class VendorComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() currentVendor: Vendor;
  vendors: Vendor[];

  constructor(public actRoute: ActivatedRoute,
              public router: Router,
              private vendorService: VendorService,
              private modalHandlerService: ModalHandlerService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.GetAll();
  }

  GetAll() {
    this.vendorService.getVendors().subscribe((data: Vendor[]) => {
      this.vendors = data;
    });
  }

  openVendorDetailsModal() {
    this.modalHandlerService.openVendorDetailsModal(this.currentVendor);
  }
}
```

When clicking on `openVendorDetailsModal` I need to open a modal with the details, My view looks like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
  <div *ngFor="let vendor of vendors" [currentVendor]= "vendor" (click)="openVendorDetailsModal(vendor)">
      <tr>
    <td>{{vendor.Id}}</td>
    <td>{{vendor.Name}}</td>
  </tr>
  </div>
</table>
```

The problem is that `[currentVendor]= "vendor"` syntax on the view is returning the error mentioned on the title. How can I bind the current vendor to the component so I can send it as parameter on the method?

Comment: Remove `[currentVendor]` and receive the vendor in your `openVendor...` at the component

Comment: I've tried that, but on the component the input property is undefined so the modal shows empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just pass the vendor by the openVendorDetailsModal method

```
  <div *ngFor="let vendor of vendors" (click)="openVendorDetailsModal(vendor)">
      <tr>
    <td>{{vendor.Id}}</td>
    <td>{{vendor.Name}}</td>
  </tr>
  </div>
```

and you can use vender parameter

```
  openVendorDetailsModal(vender) {
    this.modalHandlerService.openVendorDetailsModal(vender);
  }
```

if you want to save a refrence of passed vernder set the curentVender i n the body of the method

```
  openVendorDetailsModal(v) {
    this.currentVendor = v;
    this.modalHandlerService.openVendorDetailsModal(v);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

What I  mean is to do this:

```
openVendorDetailsModal(vendor) {
   this.modalHandlerService.openVendorDetailsModal(vendor);
}
```

In the template remove the `[currentVendor]` and keep passing the vendo to `openVendorDetailsModal`. Hope it helps.

Comment: I have you checked what is in `vendors`?